# JPA update a object creates a new one in a ManyToMany Relation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, java-8

I'm having issues while trying to update objects with JPA. The problem instead of updating an existing object, it creates new ones along with new embedded data.

Here is my java code:

First entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worksite")
public class Worksite {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double latitude;  
 
    private Set<WorksiteDevice> worksiteDevices = new HashSet<WorksiteDevice>();
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "worksite_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
 
    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
 
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
 
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "worksite", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    public Set<WorksiteDevice> getWorksiteDevices() {
        return worksiteDevices;
    }
 
    public void setWorksiteDevices(Set<WorksiteDevice> worksiteDevices) {
        this.worksiteDevices = worksiteDevices;
    }
      
}
```

Second Entity:
the device name has a unique constraint in the database. This is to prevent the user from entering the same device multiple times

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device {
    private long id;
    private String DeviceName;
 
    private Set<WorksiteDevice> worksiteDevices = new HashSet<WorksiteDevice>();
     
         
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "device_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    public String getDeviceName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.deviceName = name;
    }
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<WorksiteDevice> getWorksiteDevices() {
        return worksiteDevices;
    }
 
    public void setWorksiteDevices(Set<WorksiteDevice> worksiteDevices) {
        this.worksiteDevices = worksiteDevices;
    }
```

Join Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worksite_device")
public class WorksiteDevice {
    private long id;
    private Worksite worksite;
    private Device device;
     
    // additional fields
    private Integer deviceCount;

 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "worksite_device_id")
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "worksite_id")
   private Worksite worksite;
 
    public void setWorksite(Worksite worksite) {
        this.worksite = worksite;
    }
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "device_id")

 
    public void setDevice(Device device) {
        this.device = device;
    }
 
    public Integer getDeviceCount() {
        return deviceCount;
    }
 
    public void setDeviceCount(Integer deviceCount) {
        this.deviceCount = deviceCount;
    }

}
```

I have a DTO class in which I get from the user interface the name of the devices and the number of devices used in a worksite.

```
public class WorksiteDeviceDTO extends  BaseDTO{

    private Long id;
    private int            deviceCount;
    private String         deviceName;
    private Worksite        worksite;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getDeviceCount() {
        return deviceCount;
    }
 
    public void setDeviceCount(Integer deviceCount) {
        this.deviceCount = deviceCount;
    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        deviceName = deviceName;
    }    


}
```

I save the DTO objects in a list that I iterate before saving in the database. Here is how i do this:
I save first the worksite object and then the number of devices and names used in a worksite

```
worksiteService.saveWorksite(worksite);
final Map<String, Geraete> deviceByName = worksiteDeviceDtos.stream()
        .map(worksiteDeviceDTO::getDeviceName)
        .map(this::getOrSaveDeviceByName)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Device::getDeviceName,
                Function.identity()));

worksiteDeviceDtos.forEach(worksiteDeviceDTO -> {
    final WorksiteDevice toSave = new WorksiteDevice();
    toSave.setWorksite(worksite);
    toSave.setDevice(deviceByName.get(worksiteDeviceDTO.getDeviceName()));
    toSave.setDeviceCount(worksiteDeviceDTO.getDeviceCount());
    worksiteDeviceService.saveWorksiteDevice(toSave);
```

I check with this Method if a Devicename already in a Database exist. If so, I'll get it back. If not, I create a new Object with the new name.

```
@Transactional
public Device getOrSaveDeviceByName(String DeviceName) {
    return DeviceNameService.findByName(DeviceName)
            .orElseGet(() -> geraeteService.saveNewGeraetWithName(DeviceName));
}
```

when I change the name of a device in the user interface and I keep the number of devices, a new object is created with the modified name. I don't know how to solve this problem. Someone would have an idea. I also tried to work with a compound key but I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating and saving a new instance all the time, regardless if you "found" a device by that name. You should filter out the elements that you found.